# About Euclidean geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

If I have system of axioms from which I can deduce all theorems of absolute geometry, and among this axioms I have some of the variants of fifth Euclid postulate, does it mean that this system will produce whole Euclidean geometry ?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: Yes indeed because it is a subset of axioms that went into produced Euclidean geometry.